# I keep getting "signal 1: SIGABRT" in swift 3 and I don't know how to get around it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, appdelegate

I've checked all of my connections and ***NONE*** of them are broken.  I've reconnected all of them and checked everything but I keep getting this error.  It comes in the first line of the App Delegate and I don't know why.  Here's the code.

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


    @IBOutlet weak var MITImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var StanfordImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var HarvardImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func MITSafariViewControllerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = NSURL(string: MITUrl)!
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url as URL)
        present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func StanfordSafariViewControllerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = NSURL(string: StanfordUrl)!
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url as URL)
        present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func HarvardSafariViewControllerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = NSURL(string: HarvardUrl)!
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url as URL)
        present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func imageChangeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePickerClass().imagePickerControllerMIT(picker: imagePicker)
    }
    @IBAction func imageChangeButtonStanford(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePickerClass().imagePickerControllerStanford(picker: imagePicker)
    }

    @IBAction func imageChangeButtonHarvard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePickerClass().imagePickerControllerHarvard(picker: imagePicker)
    }

    var MITUrl = "http://web.mit.edu"
    var StanfordUrl = "http://stanford.edu"
    var HarvardUrl = "http://www.harvard.edu"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self


               var logos = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MIT Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Stanford Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Harvard Logo")]

        var pos1 = Int()
        var pos2 = Int()
        var pos3 = Int()

        pos1 = 0
        pos2 = 1
        pos3 = 2

        self.MITImageView.image = logos[pos1]
        self.StanfordImageView.image = logos[pos2]
        self.HarvardImageView.image = logos[pos3]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}



class imagePickerClass : DetailsViewController {

    var pos1 = Int()
    var pos2 = Int()
    var pos3 = Int()
    var MITImage = Int()
    var StanfordImage = Int()
    var HarvardImage = Int()



    init (){
        pos1 = 0
        pos2 = 1
        pos3 = 2
        MITImage = 3
        StanfordImage = 3
        HarvardImage = 3

        let code = NSCoder()
        super.init(coder: code)!
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func imagePickerControllerMIT(picker: UIImagePickerController) {


            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            weak var weakSelf = self

            weakSelf?.present((weakSelf?.imagePicker)!, animated: true, completion: nil)



                self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    let imageSelected = [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
                    var logos = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MIT Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Stanford Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Harvard Logo"), imageSelected]
                    self.MITImageView.image = logos[self.MITImage]


            })


    }

    func imagePickerControllerStanford(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            weak var weakSelf = self
            weakSelf?.present((weakSelf?.imagePicker)!, animated: true, completion: {
            let  imageSelected = [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            var logos = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MIT Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Stanford Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Harvard Logo"), imageSelected]
            self.MITImageView.image = logos[self.StanfordImage]

            })

        })
    }


    func imagePickerControllerHarvard(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            weak var weakSelf = self
            weakSelf?.present((weakSelf?.imagePicker)!, animated: true, completion: {
            let imageSelected = [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            var logos = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MIT Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Stanford Logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Harvard Logo"), imageSelected]
            self.MITImageView.image = logos[self.HarvardImage]

            })
        })
    }



}
```

Heres the error

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,       UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

If you could help me figure this out that would be great.

Comment: can you add the log of the error?

Comment: Might be way off, but just double-checking that the `init` method that throws a fatal error in `imagePickerClass` isn't getting called? It sounds like you're using storyboards (?) and I believe if the image picker object is loaded from a storyboard that is the `init` that will be called.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the first line of the app delegate. Which line of code is crashing. And copy and paste the exact message you're getting. Also copy and paste the stack trace of the crash into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First want to say that I am using **Xcode 7.0** and  **IOS 9.0**. And I have also got a same problem in `objective-c`. I found the cause of exception simply debugging my code (Basically which line is responsible for it). And I am going to share with you. Though your question is `swift` related, I am just trying to help about the `signal 1: SIGABRT`. It's may help you.

**1.** First set a `debug pointer` of your code at any line. click `show the break point navigator` icon.

**2.** click `create a break point` icon.

**3.** click `Add Exception BreakPoint`.

**4.** Right click on the `All Exception` and click `Edit BreakPoint`.

**5.** select `objective-c` as an option of 'Exception'.

And run your application. It will take you to the corresponding line for which you get `SIGABRT`.

[image]